# How do I call mongoDB CRUD method from handler?

Tags: mongodb, go

I've written a simple MongoDB package with some CRUD methods:

```
package backend

import "labix.org/v2/mgo"

type MongoDBConn struct {
    session *mgo.Session
}

type ToDo struct {
    Title       string
    Description string
}

func NewMongoDBConn() *MongoDBConn {
    return &MongoDBConn{}
}

func (m *MongoDBConn) Connect(url string) *mgo.Session {
    session, err := mgo.Dial(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    m.session = session
    return m.session
}

func (m *MongoDBConn) Stop() {
    m.session.Close()
}

func (m *MongoDBConn) AddToDo(title, description string) (err error) {
    c := m.session.DB("test").C("people")
    err = c.Insert(&ToDo{title, description})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I have a server.go where I create a Http Server and have handlers for the different URLs. I'd like to be able to connect to MongoDB and call the AddToDo method within a specific handler. I can connect to the DB from the main method of my server:

```
import (
    "./backend"
       //other boilerplate imports
)

func AddHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("serving %v %v", request.Method, request.URL.Path[1:])
    if request.Method != "POST" {
        serve404(writer)
        return
    }
    title := request.FormValue("title")
    description := request.FormValue("description")
    fmt.Fprintf(writer, " title description %v %v", title, description)
//I can't call mongoConn.AddToDo(title, description) from here

}    
func main() {
        //connect to mongoDB
        mongoConn := backend.NewMongoDBConn()
        _ = mongoConn.Connect("localhost")
        defer mongoConn.Stop()
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to call mongoConn.AddToDo(title, description string) method from the handler. Should I create a global db connection variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple method:

**1.global database session**

```
package main


import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "./backend"
)


var mongoConn * backend.MongoDBConn

func AddHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("serving %v %v", r.Method, r.URL.Path[1:])
    if r.Method != "POST" {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Not POST Method ")
        return
    }
    title := r.FormValue("title")
    description := r.FormValue("description")



    fmt.Fprintf(w, " title description %v %v", title, description)
//I can't call mongoConn.AddToDo(title, description) from here
    mongoConn.AddToDo(title, description)
}    

const AddForm = `
<html><body>
<form method="POST" action="/add">
Name: <input type="text" name="title">
Age: <input type="text" name="description">
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
</body></html>
`
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   fmt.Fprintln(w, AddForm)
}

func main() {
        //connect to mongoDB


       mongoConn = backend.NewMongoDBConn()
        _ = mongoConn.Connect("localhost")
        defer mongoConn.Stop()

        http.HandleFunc("/", Index)
        http.HandleFunc("/add", AddHandler)

        log.Println("Start Server:")
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
        }
}
```

**2.a new db connection on every request**

```
import (
    "./backend"
       //other boilerplate imports
)

func AddHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("serving %v %v", request.Method, request.URL.Path[1:])
    if request.Method != "POST" {
        serve404(writer)
        return
    }
    title := request.FormValue("title")
    description := request.FormValue("description")
    fmt.Fprintf(writer, " title description %v %v", title, description)
    //................
    mongoConn := backend.NewMongoDBConn()
    _ = mongoConn.Connect("localhost")
    mongoConn.AddToDo(title, description)
    //....................
    mongoConn.Stop()

} 

......
```

**a better solution:**

> You could create a pool of db sessions, then before processing the
>   request you pick one and put in the context of that request. Then
>   after the request is done you push the connection back to the pool.
>
> If the pool is empty you create a new connection If the pool is full
>   you close the connection

For more information, click [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/gjvK4zcYy6U).

Comment: The first solution of a global variable, I had tried it earlier and it doesn't work. I keep getting this error:
http: panic serving [::1]:55642: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Comment: define a global variable:`var mongoConn *benkend.MongoDBConn`, connect mongodb in main function:`mongoConn = backend.NewMongoDBConn()`.I hava  change the code above, it works.

Comment: There's no point in creating a pool of db sessions. mgo will internally cache resources when a session is closed, and will reuse those resources whenever a new session is created.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a global session is an easy way to handle that. Then, at the top of every handler, you can do something along the lines of:

```
func handler(...) {
    session := globalSession.Copy()
    defer session.Close()
}
```

so that each handler gets its own session to work with.

Note that copying and closing sessions are cheap operations, that internally will work against a pool of connections rather than establishing new connections for every session created.

Comment: First thanks for answering these questions. As the main developer of mgo, it's specially authoritative.

I'm looking at the code in mgo/session.go, Apply() for instance already clones the session so why would it be needed to create copies of a globalsession ourselves?