# fatal error out of memory

Tags: go, mgo

So I wrote a daemon in go that handles around 800k documents and i'm having an out of memory problem.

From what i saw when getting the documents from mongodb the memory usage increases with every loop.

```
func main() {
session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
if err != nil { panic(err) }
defer session.Close()

subscriptionsC  = session.DB("sm").C("subscriptions")
subscriptions   := []Subscription{}

for {
    subscriptions = GetSubscriptions()
```

And the other function is:

```
func GetSubscriptions()([]Subscription) {
    result  := []Subscription{}
    err    := subscriptionsC.Find(nil).Prefetch(0.0).All(&result)

    if err != nil { Log("signups_err", err.Error() + "\n") }
    return result
}
```

I don't know if it's redeclaring the array with each loop or what exactly happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `for` loop is an infinite loop and is just collecting the results from Mongo on each iteration.

Comment: Is it possible that the session is caching your results? You could try closing/recreating your subscriptionsC object on each run through the loop as a test.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815635/composer-running-out-of-memory-on-every-project-mac-os-x/64589121#64589121    follow this for get fast and quick solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is definietly being inialized in every loop because of the call to `GetSubscriptions()` and then inside the loop `result := []Subscription{}`, but I think that's not the source of the problem.

The problem could be coming from your global session, see [Database connections in web applications](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/gjvK4zcYy6U/yn6za5fyTPgJ), The proper way would be by using a session pool.

***Edit***: also see [How do I call mongoDB CRUD method from handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018864/how-do-i-call-mongodb-crud-method-from-handler)

Comment: The error I get is: http://pastebin.com/n9b0teSR . Where 139 is the "err" in GetSubscriptions() and 166 is subscriptions = GetSubscriptions()

Comment: Exactly the `err` is caused by `subscriptionsC` which is why I suspect you're ought to use another pattern instead of global session. See: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mgo-users/d62BH1iuzFc/J1cgd5gWjnUJ

Comment: Thanks man. Before doing it i tested with a $where on the query. Seems that if the number of records returned was smaller the memory usage was stable and also the garbage collection worked properly.

Comment: There's no reason to use a session pool in mgo, as resources (sockets, for example) are internally maintained in a pool. Just create and close sessions as required.

Comment: @GustavoNiemeyer I cant delete my answer as OP already selected it. if it's changed i'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Author of mgo here.

There's nothing wrong with your code, but it's incomplete, so it's always possible that something you're not showing is in fact leaking memory.

Can you provide a full example that leaks memory?

There's no point in caching/pooling sessions, by the way, because mgo internally handles pooling of resources for you. What you must do is to make sure you close the sessions you create, which the sample code does.

**Update after OP's comment below:**

> Seems that the problem is with a high amount of docs. pastebin.com/jUDmbS4z this will crash once every 10-15 mins (around 4-5 loops). It's getting around 600k docs from mongo in one loop.

Yeah, running queries that load a ridiculous amount of data in memory at once can easily create trouble for a number of reasons unrelated to mgo.. memory fragmentation, non-precise collector, etc. Just iterate over the items as they arrive as usual; it is comfortable, fast, and will dramatically reduce the amount of memory used, as you already figured.

Comment: The thing is that I changed to not get everything from the collection and that daemon is working perfectly now, no more memory leaking since  jan 7th and never restarted. Seems that the problem is with a high amount of docs. http://pastebin.com/jUDmbS4z this will crash once every 10-15 mins (around 4-5 loops). It's getting around 600k docs from mongo in one loop. I think that a forEach() instead of populating an array will fix it but also increase the number of queries.

Comment: Hah.. okay. You _are_ using a ton of memory then. That's not a leak in mgo. Updated the response.

Comment: Never said it was, i was thinking more of a golang bug but they said they fixed it with the latest release.