# Composer running out of memory on every project, Mac OS X

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I attempted to install `aws/aws-sdk-php` yesterday on one of my Laravel 4 projects using Composer, I cannot remember exactly the chain of events but it did not install successfully. Ever since, I have been receiving errors that Composer has run out of memory - `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52`.

I increased the php.ini `memory_limit` to -1 and this still occurs, both in my development and production environments (production is Cent OS 6). Installation completes successfully if I increase the `memory_limit` via the CLI when I run `composer_update` but it takes an eternity.

Is there some sort of cache that I need to clear to prevent Composer for running out of memory? I have a feeling that it is still trying to install the AWS SDK every time I run composer update.

**Composer file**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "rtablada/package-installer": "dev-master",
        "mogreet/mogreet-php": "dev-master",
        "twilio/laratwilio": "dev-master",
        "balloon/elephant.io": "dev-master",
        "facebook/php-sdk": "dev-master",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "codesleeve/asset-pipeline": "dev-master",
        "natxet/CssMin": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/libraries"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: I would like to investigate this - can you post the composer file you're trying to run, or a modified version if it currently uses private stuff.

Comment: Sure, hang on.. it's happening with two projects, one that I attempted to install AWS SDK on and one that I did not. I will post the one I attempted

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815635/composer-running-out-of-memory-on-every-project-mac-os-x/64589121#64589121    follow this for get fast and quick solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

EDIT: Before going any further always make sure you're running the latest version of composer, you can update it via `composer self-update`

When you run `composer update` it will calculate the most up-to-date gitref for each of your libraries (or the latest release) and then will install that version of the library. It will then store these versions in the `composer.lock` file.

When you run `composer install`, it simply installs the versions defined in the `composer.lock` file.

The reason `composer update` takes so long and uses so much memory is because it has to trace every library's version, compare it with the version you have defined in your `composer.json` and then check all of that library's dependencies. This is quite an intensive process.

I find that running composer using `hhvm` (you can install it [here](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-OSX-10.9)) speeds up the `composer update`  process massively.

Short of that, you just have to live with the high memory usage and increase it in your `php.ini` file. Make sure you update the one that is relevant for your CLI.

EDIT: You should never run `composer update` in the production environment. You should only update your dependencies when you're developing, and then use `composer install` to install your last used set of composer dependencies when you're in a production environment.

Comment: When I add a new package to my composer.json file, is it best to run composer install instead of composer update? Also, I did not have any problems before trying to install AWS PHP SDK, is there any way to undo whatever caused this to start? I'm still trying to get the hang of all this Composer business.

Comment: As you add more dependencies your `composer update` will take longer - it has more to calculate. I have just found a discussion [thread here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2704) which might be related to your issue - I highly recommend installing HHVM and running `composer update` via that instead

Comment: Okay, I'll check out HHVM. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: commiting the composer.lock file was enough for me

Answer (score 22):

At the present moment there is a bug on Composer causing memory to be exhausted.

If you do

```
composer install
```

Then delete a folder inside vendor

```
rm -rf vendor/laravel
```

and do

```
composer update
```

You'll get this error. It's a bug, it is not supposed to run out of memory.

For now you can fix it for yourself by doing:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

Also, check [this thread](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898), they are about to fix this.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, `php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update` is the only way I can run it at present

Comment: In my case i needed `php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar update` command

Answer (score 17):

try this. It fixed my problem.I guess better way to fix it rather than update memory.

```
sudo composer self-update
```

Comment: I get: [InvalidArgumentException] Command "self-update" is not defined.

Answer (score 6):

Easy, type this commands:

`rm -rf vendor/`

`rm -rf composer.lock`

`php composer install --prefer-dist`

Should work for low memory machines or others memory problems

Comment: I think the problem resolved with an update to Composer. This has become a distant memory

Comment: Good. The command "composer update" takes too much memory, maybe because do comparations...

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this too but I use `brew`.

```
composer --version
brew info composer
brew upgrade composer
...
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
composer 1.9.0 -> 1.9.2
==> Upgrading composer 
...
```

which still did not fix my `composer require drupal/environment_indicator`

Using the php memory limit mentioned by others fixed this finally.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 `which composer` require drupal/environment_indicator
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're having 8 GB of Ram or more, then you can surely increase the PHP memory_limit to 1 GB or else to 512MB. On your Mac open terminal-

1. Find the PHP memory limit config file.

```
php --ini
```

2. Edit the `php-memory-limits.ini` file.

```
nano /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

3. Increase Memory limit to 1 GB

```
memory_limit = 1G
```

4. Verify if the Memory limit increased or not.

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

5. Restart PHP service.

```
brew services restart php
```

And done. Increasing the memory limit also reduces a little bit of `composer update` completion time, which is good.

If you wanna speed up `composer update` time. Try installing the popular - [Prestissimo](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo) package.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it was taking so much memory is because of the behaviour of Composer when treating packages and the replace keyword.

The idea behind replace was that it allowed you to do two things:

- Replace a standard library version with your own version. e.g. if you find an example in 'symfony/yaml' you could fork it, fix the bug and then release it as a package called "nightmicu/yaml". You could then tell composer that "nightmicu/yaml" replaces "symfony/yaml". Then any other package that you install that depends on "symfony/yaml" will be satisfied by having "nightmicu/yaml".
- It allows people to release packages both as single components, as well as a complete library e.g. the symfony framework package replaces each of its components packages.

The problem is that the replace keyword, up to about 1 hour ago, worked globally across the whole of Packagist.

This means that for popular libraries, that have been forked and renamed there is a huge amount of possible versions to install. This is what was causing a huge memory usage, and taking a long time to process.

If you get the latest version of composer.phar, it should be better now, as 'replace' now works differently, by only working on packages named in the root composer.json i.e. you have to explicitly use a package in your composer.json to have it be either replaceable or act as a replacement, though I haven't been able to test it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to fix this on Windows is:

Goto: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin

Edit **composer.bat**

Change it to:

```
@ECHO OFF
php -d memory_limit=-1 "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```

Save the file and run:

composer selfupdate

Comment: Change what to what? Should I replace the batch files with your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

do not do any thing only try this code if your version is 1.*:

```
 composer self-update --2
```

i was facing many problem then  i given **memory_limit : 10G**. after that i was getting same issue then i try to update composer version then it gone fix.
you can check compser version

```
 composer --version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
`COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` composer
like this picker
[image]

Comment: sorry, first and last time