# Running out of memory trying to install envoy globally on production server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I have a DigitalOcean VPS I pay 15 bucks monthly for, I'm trying to install laravel envoy task runner with this command:

```
composer global require laravel/envoy
```

But I get the following error:

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 459276288) (tried to allocate 2131644 bytes) in /usr/share/php/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 419

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 459276288) (tried to allocate 2131644 bytes) in /usr/share/php/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 419
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: contact DigitalOcean support

Comment: check this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Well, I do not know what your 15 bucks account is about. The warning also says "SSDs hard drives" and "If you need to improve the performance ... we will recommend upgrading your Droplet.". If in your DO account you are allowed 459276288 of memory, contact DigitalOcean support, as the other comment says,

Comment: you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299302/composer-update-failed-out-of-memory) thread too