# Problem using knp-menu-bundle with Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting the following error when trying to install a 3rd Party bundle:

From my Symfony project, I run:  composer require knplabs/knp-menu-bundle dev-master

which returns:

[InvalidArgumentException]
  Package knplabs/knp-menu-bundle at version dev-master has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP versio
  n (5.6)

Using symfony 3.4

I check my php version

php -v: returns ->PHP 7.0.33 (cli) 
which php: returns -> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.33/bin/php

After updating my bash provile with vim ~/.bash_profile to use /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.33/bin/php, I expected that would solve the problem.

I also tried composer require knplabs/knp-menu-bundle ^2.0. which returns:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

I bumped up the memory several times up 1100M but still the same problem. I saw other posts suggesting to set the memory to unlimited which i do not want to do.

Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance,

Conor

Comment: Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299302/composer-update-failed-out-of-memory)

ps.: please try to format your question properly. As a new contributor I would suggest you to read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).
Thanks and welcome on StackOverflow.

Comment: Did you try to add flag --ignore-platform-reqs? `composer require <package> --ignore-platform-reqs` local php version may differ from sever version so local composer might have issue with server and vice versa.