# composer still exhausted even allocated with bigger memory

Tags: php, composer-php

Already updated the `memory_limit` on php.ini by about `1G` and doing also `php -d memory_limit=1G composer.phar update` and I can see the allowed memory is bigger than the displayed memory attempt `1610612736` where composer says `tried to allocate 4096 bytes` any help, ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether your system provides more memory? Additionally, what have you tried to resolve this? This looks like either a problem of Composer being too old (there were a lot of fixes about memory leaks), or a problem of too loose version constraints

Comment: @NicoHaase running on windows 10, i7 10th, 16gb ddr5 (65% available), just to make sure, did uninstall the current composer and downloaded and installed a fresh one from the composer website, same error unfortunately

Comment: And what about checking the version constraints? Can you share your `composer.json` such that others could inspect it for possible problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `composer diagnose`.

The `diagnose` command performs automated checks for many common problems. This can help you spot find potential bottlenecks/bugs if there are any.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#diagnose

Answer (score 0):

**From Composer documentation:**

> Note: Composer internally increases the memory_limit to 1.5G.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

Have this a go:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update
```

If this does not work there are more solutions here:

[Composer Update failed -- out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299302/composer-update-failed-out-of-memory)