# Getting Error on composer run to install modules "VirtualAlloc"

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8, drupal-modules

**Getting this error on "composer require drupal/module-name"**.
I want to install a module on my drupal site but it always returns me this error.

```
VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.


VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.


VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.


VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.


Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1711276032) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in 
phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on 
line 223
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer Update failed -- out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299302/composer-update-failed-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 0):

Update on your php.ini file's:  memory_limit= XXXM

Replace XXXM value by the memory that you wanna allocate.

Or replace XXXM by -1 to negate memory limit condition.

Comment: Are you sure that you edit the right php.ini file?
if you execute :
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
Did your memomy limit change?

Comment: Yes i am pretty sure about the memory limit.

Comment: Did you restarted your server. Did your memomy limit change after this? If it persists, do as @ Nico-hasse said and check [composer-update-failed-out-of-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299302/composer-update-failed-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual memory Error on composer run Solution (Windows)

1. Download PHP 7.3+ and place on a folder on c drive
2. Change the environment variable path of PHP to new php
3. Set the memory limit to -1 in  PHP 7.3+ ini file Also uncomment the required extensions.
4. Run Composer