# Composer require runs out of memory. PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to add HWIOAuthBundle to my project by running the below command.

```
composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle
```

HWIOAuthBundle github: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

When I try to run composer require I am getting the out of memory error.

> Using version ^0.6.0@dev for hwi/oauth-bundle Using version ^1.2@dev
>   for php-http/guzzle6-adapter Using version ^1.10@dev for
>   php-http/httplug-bundle ./composer.json has been updated Loading
>   composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies
>   (including require-dev)
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in
>   phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.4.2/libexec/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 67108864 bytes) in
>   phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.4.2/libexec/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220

I tried setting the memory_limit to 2G in my php.ini file but did not work.  I found my php.ini by running `php -i | grep php.ini`

Comment: Have you done a composer self-update lately?  Not sure if the 1.4.2 in your error message indicates version 1.4.2 but the latest version of composer is 1.6.2.  And how much physical memory do you have?  Is it a vm or cloud server?

Comment: @Cerad Yes - I did a composer self-update before and my composer version is 1.6.2

Comment: @Cerad this is on my local machine and I definitely should have enough memory

Comment: When experiencing this issue on projects where Composer ran fine previously, I'd advise running `composer self-update --rollback`. I started running into memory exhaustion with v.1.9.3, which stopped when I rolled back to 1.8.6.

Comment: Does no-one else think that it's pretty crazy that running `composer require` can use more than 1.5G of memory?  When I first saw this I thought it has to be a bug in composer.  Setting the memory limit to -1 did work for me... but how on earth is 1.5G not enough?  Can composer really need so much?

Comment: See this [memory-limit-errors](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815635/composer-running-out-of-memory-on-every-project-mac-os-x/64589121#64589121    follow this for get fast and quick solution.

Comment: In my case, I was missing a swap partition. More info: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7348#issuecomment-414178276

Answer (score 592, accepted):

To get the current memory_limit value, run:

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

Try increasing the limit in your `php.ini` file (ex. `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` for Debian-like systems):

```
; Use -1 for unlimited or define an explicit value like 2G
memory_limit = -1
```

Or, you can increase the limit with a command-line argument:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle
```

To get loaded php.ini files location try:

```
php --ini
```

Another quick solution:

```
php composer.phar COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle
```

Or just:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle
```

Comment: COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update works for me also.

Comment: Thanks for the command `php --ini` ! in php 7.4 you have a different php ini file (php-cli.ini) for clid

Comment: using ```php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar install``` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: is memory_limit= -1 a good solution ? it seems like it removes any memory consumption limit and can use up all of it.

Comment: @kamoteulalo `php -d` affects only the running command, btw memory_limit helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available memory on a server, so if your code is well written so there's no fear to set memory_limit to unlimited. but still, it's not recommended.

Comment: On Windows, use `SET COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1`

Comment: For me, inside a vagrant machine and using composer as part of another script, it works by prepending `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` to the command.

Comment: When using php and composer inside a dev docker container, this is what worked for me `docker-compose exec -e COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 <container_id> composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle`

Answer (score 429):

In my case I was trying to require [this package](https://github.com/huddledigital/zendesk-laravel) when I got this error.

You can run like this, and you don't have to update the PHP INI file:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require huddledigital/zendesk-laravel
```

Comment: Also helped. My PHP limit was 128MB, but the error message said that PHP composer limit is 1,5GB (which means it's configured elsewhere for this particular case). So modification of php.ini didn't help, but this answer did.

Comment: Thank you, putting the constant `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` before the `composer require xyz` made it work (the accepted answer did not).

Comment: you saved my day, in my case, i am instalingl `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

Answer (score 104):

Another solution from the [manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors):

Composer also respects a memory limit defined by the `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT` environment variable:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer.phar <...>
```

Or in my case

```
export COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
composer <...>
```

Comment: On mac I edited `~/.bash_profile` to add `alias composer="COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer"` and that solved it for me. Be sure to source the file after the change or restart your terminal

Comment: perfect solution (no need to change any php configuration)

Answer (score 89):

Same problem, none of anything related to "memory_limit" worked, but..

```
composer self-update --2
```

..solved my problem. (upgrade: 1.10.17 -> 2.0.4)

Comment: For those `composer self-update --2` - did not worked and error had happened. 
`composer self-update --stable` did the job :)

Comment: others solutions didnt work, hopefully u wrote yours...u made my day thank you

Comment: Merci!, you saved my job.

Comment: composer self-update --stable
Easy and fast way, thanx!

Comment: `composer self-update --stable` then `composer update` worked.

Answer (score 61):

On Windows 10;

Goto `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`

Edit: `composer.bat` and add `memory_limit=-1` in the last line as shown below.

```
@echo OFF
:: in case DelayedExpansion is on and a path contains ! 
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
php -d memory_limit=-1 "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```

Problem solved ;)

Comment: the best one for me, almost all of them didn't work for me.

Comment: I also had to update *composer* file without .bat extension (adding same -d memory_limit=-1) to last line.

Comment: In windows, the location of `composer.bat` need not be `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin` always, but I guess that is the default location. However, if someone want to find location of `composer.bat` just need to run the `where` command: like `where composer`. That will show exact location.

Answer (score 48):

Since none of the previous answers included `set` it took me a bit to figure out how to do it in Windows without altering the php.ini, but here's what worked for me:

```
set COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle
```

Comment: This is the best answer for Windows environment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 38):

I have bypassed the problem in a Homestead Laravel (vagrant) virtual machine running the composer commands preceded by `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1`:

Examples

To update Composer:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
```

To install a package:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require spatie/laravel-translatable
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Is it globally updated or only for that specific command?

Comment: Just a temporary solution for that specific command.

Comment: Thanks amigo ! Thats best solution for win10

Comment: I am using laravel 8 and I had to add env before the command to something like this env COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update

Answer (score 30):

For this error in macOS Catalina and macOS Big Sur use this line:

`php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update --no-plugins`

I used this line to update on Symfony 5. This command also worked with laravel 7.

Comment: It worked for me! 
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar require laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss --dev

Comment: How do I fixed this permanently ?
I need to redo it every time creating new project.
Any advise ?

Answer (score 29):

Just set the `memory_limit` specifying the full route of your composer.phar file and update, in my case with the command:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 C:/wamp64/composer.phar update
```

Comment: Also `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer.phar update` works. See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

Comment: on ubuntu use this
`php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer update`

Comment: COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer  works for me too.. @mayid Thank you. :+1

Answer (score 27):

Sometimes the problem is in the composer memory limit. In my case, I tried increasing the php memory limit but still got the error.
You can use `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` to get around that.
Use it as a prefix:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require the/library
```

You have to prefix it again in the future.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are working with windows CLI, this is the right answer for you.

Answer (score 21):

It was recently identified that Composer consumes high CPU + memory on packages that have a lot of historical tags. See [composer/composer#7577](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7577)

A workaround to this problem is using `symfony/flex` or https://github.com/rubenrua/symfony-clean-tags-composer-plugin

```
composer global require rubenrua/symfony-clean-tags-composer-plugin
```

Comment: Just need to have the plugin installed globally? Nothing else to be done? Could you please explain what this plugin actually do? Does is reduce memory usage by composer in such cases?

Answer (score 20):

Just in case you get a composer error with:

> Could not open input file: composer

run:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer require ...
```

Answer (score 14):

what about windows?

i use windows 10 and this command worked for me,

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" update
```

Answer (score 13):

Composer 2.0 preview is available now: https://github.com/composer/composer/releases
Fixed issue for me. You can set up a preview with `composer self-update --preview`

EDIT: Composer 2 with memory tuning released

Answer (score 8):

in windows by xampp i just changed:

```
;memory_limit=512M
```

in php.ini to:

```
memory_limit =-1
```

then restart the Apache by xampp

this is the result:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit =-1
;memory_limit=512M
```

Comment: This works man Thank you man on  2021Jan15

Answer (score 7):

> You can use a **specific php Version** when running **Composer**

If, like me, for some reason, you are using **PHP 32 bits** even though your computer is 64 bits, this will always limit the amount of memory allocated to Composer. I solved my problem this way:

- Install a 64 bits php version somewhere on your computer (let's say in C:/php64)
- In composer (using cygwin in my case), run:

`COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 C:/php64/php.exe ../composer.phar update`

Comment: This suggestion worked for me! Thanks. A note is that you also need to update the system environment variable to use the new 64bit version globally.

Answer (score 6):

On Mac php 7.4

run

```
php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

If Additional .ini files parsed:
memory_limit needs to be changed in

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

As Jose Seie writes, set memory to

```
memory_limit = -1 or memory_limit = 1G
```

Answer (score 5):

Just want to share my situation on this matter.

Problem context:

1. Running composer in a vagrant box.
2. Was getting this message after try to run composer require "laravel-doctrine/orm:~1.4.13":

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
>   Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

3. Have tried setting php.ini memory limit to -1. (still not working).

Solution:

1. Apparently my composer.json and composer.lock has some issues. 
   Ran $ composer validate, and the result was:
   "The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json, it is recommended that you run `composer update`."
2. So I ran $ composer update, and all dependencies are resolved. Imho, when the dependencies has some issues, maybe the tree building is out of sync, hence the out of memory issue.

Hope this helps anyone out there.

Answer (score 4):

For Macbook:
run command `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile` to edit bash_profile then add `alias composer="COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer"` in that file, then save and exit.

Hope this will solve the problem; Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

I condensed or packaged up the useful and accepted answer here into reusable (zsh) aliases/functions, for quicker and easier-to-remember reuse:

```
# composer high-memory
composermem() {
  php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
}
alias composerbig='COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer $1'
```

(`php composer.phar` is already aliased to `composer` on the system).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my composer version was 1.x which was back-dated.
After upgrading the version to 2.x it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to not require a package before making sure the vendor folder exists.

Check if you have done `composer install` before. You may be just cloned the repository to your machine. So, you have to install the old packages before requiring a new one. Or you may want to include this option `--profile` to your composer command to see the timing and memory usage information.

Answer (score -2):

I am using php7.2 and the size is set to `memory_limit = 512M` by default.
to increase the size, you need to locate `php.ini`.

In `Wamp`, it is located in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.23\php.ini`. Please watch out for the PHP version as it is the name folder, in my case I have `php7.2.23`

In `Laragon`, it is located in `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.23-Win32-VC15-x64\php.ini` as was in my case.

If you don't want to allow unlimited space, you can set whatever size that is convenient to you, in my case I did `memory_limit = 2G`

if you want to allow unlimited space, you can change to `memory_limit = -1`

Answer (score -2):

Running `composer dump-autoload` solves it for me.