# Getting issue when install composer into Laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

I want to install Laravel 7 Image Intervention using following command

```
    composer require intervention/image
```

Getting Below errors see in image

[image]

I dont know why this happen? If anyone have idea then please let me know. Please help me in this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer require runs out of memory. PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212475/composer-require-runs-out-of-memory-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-161)

Answer (score 0):

During the install process, composer is needing to use more memory that is available to it.

You can either increase this memory limit, or use a temporary environment variable to set/remove it.

Try `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require intervention/image`

This will run the require process with no memory limit.

Comment: I am geeting this error when do this command 'COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I use a *nix system. You are essentially setting an environment variable. Try searching google for how to set an environment variable on Windows :)