# Composer how to update from version 1 to version 2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

In my case I use webklex/laravel-imap.

I had `v1.4.1` after I run `composer update webklex/laravel-imap` it updated to `v1.6.2`, but there is already version `2.1.1`, which I want to use.

It seems that composer update tries to maintain compability, but how would I correctly update to the newest version?

I tried `composer require webklex/laravel-imap`, which gave me an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar
```

Comment: Which version of Composer are you using?

Answer (score 1):

composer require would be enough to update the version but it makes memory exhaust limit so often. if the newer version is compatible with your laravel version then update composer.json file with your desired version in require object like

`"webklex/laravel-imap": "^2.1"`

and then run

`composer update webklex/laravel-imap`

composer update does not make memory exhaust limit so often but in case you again get memory exhaust error you have to update your composer memory limit, [heres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212475/composer-require-runs-out-of-memory-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-161) an answer how to do that.

Comment: Beware that using `composer update` will also update all other dependencies to the latest available versions matching the requirements, which may be an issue. Running `composer update webklex/laravel-imap` is therefore safer.