# Cannot install laravel/socialite package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to install Socialite Package getting this error :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted
> (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in
> phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php
> on line 126

I have change changed memory_limit in my php.ini file but facing same issue, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` as is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212475/composer-require-runs-out-of-memory-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-161? or did you use another value ?

Comment: @Luuk:i ran this command set `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` but getting same issue

Comment: Did you also change the correct php.ini, as is explained in this hread?  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/allowed-memory-size-of-1610612736-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-4096-bytes

Comment: @Luuk: yes i have set `memory_limit` to -1 in php.ini but getting same error

Comment: Which composer version are you using? If you are still on version 1, consider upgrading to version 2. Or run the command with  -vvv to see where exactly composer uses so much memory.