# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar

Tags: laravel, livewires

composer require livewire/livewire
Using version ^2.3 for livewire/livewire
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
C:\Users\vits\vitsagro>composer require livewire/livewire

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer require runs out of memory. PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212475/composer-require-runs-out-of-memory-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-161)

Answer (score -1):

Execute the following command for the package

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require livewire/livewire
```

**or**

Try increasing the limit in your php.ini file

Use -1 for unlimited

```
memory_limit = -1
```

Don't forget to restrat your Apache server after this

Comment: Kindly mark this answer accepted if it does solve your problem.

Comment: COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require livewire/livewire
'COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.