# Running out of memory PHP Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I have Laravel project running in Ubuntu 16.04. I migrate it to mac OS Mojave and it running out of memory. Both has identical `memory_limit = 128M`.
Composer install everything correctly but the times out when post-autoload-dump i.e. `php artisan package:discover`.
**NOTE:** Works perfectly in Ubuntu.
So, what's the problem behind it?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory_limit in php.ini?

Comment: yes i did but no luck

Comment: tried composer self-update?

Comment: yes i did but no luck

Comment: I have wrote an answer for this . please test it

Comment: check this answer it seems duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815635/composer-running-out-of-memory-on-every-project-mac-os-x/218193699

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer running out of memory on every project, Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815635/composer-running-out-of-memory-on-every-project-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with DB connection, i used mysql 5.7 in Ubuntu and mysql 8 in mac OS. I fixed the problem by adding

```
'modes'  => [
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
        ]
```

in database.php

Answer (score 2):

At the present moment there is a bug on Composer causing memory to be exhausted.

If you do

```
composer install
```

Then delete a folder inside vendor

```
rm -rf vendor/laravel
```

and do

```
composer update
```

You'll get this error. It's a bug, it is not supposed to run out of memory.

For now you can fix it for yourself by doing:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

Also, check [this thread](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898), they are about to fix this.

Comment: the problem was never with composer. The problem was with post-autoload-dump in laravel.
 php artisan package:discover

Comment: @BijeshShrestha Please post what error you are getting when running the command